# Text formating - write out words following XY

Tags: matlab

I am fairly new to MATLAB and for my homework I have a block of text from which I need to select words after "and" or "And" and then replace every letter X for letter Y. I know how to do this in python through .split() and cycling through a sting(word) where I search for X. However, in matlab I am lost. Could you please tell me if there are some equivalent commands ? Something along the commands like

```
    fileread
    textscan
    fseek
```

Thank you

EDIT:

What I actaully meant was that from a string:

```
    str = 'I like apples and pineapples and other fruit'
```

I need to obtain

```
    'pineapples'
    'other'
```

and return these with 'e' switched for 'z'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regular [case-insensitive regular expressions](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/regexpi.html). Find everything after `and` or `And`, and switch `X` with `Y`:

```
str = 'This is a text with X and X and Z'
[startIndex,endIndex] = regexpi(str,'and');
str2 = str(endIndex(1) + 1 : end)
str2(str2 == 'X') = 'Y';
str = [str(1:endIndex), str2]

str =

This is a text with X and Y and Z
```

It is a bit messy. I guess it could be done simpler, but at least it works! If you don't case about the case of `X`, use [`strcmpi`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/strcmpi.html) instead of `==`.

## UPDATE#:

After your comment, I guess this should work:

```
[startIndex,endIndex] = regexpi(str,'and');
str2 = str(endIndex(1) + 1 : end);
words = regexp(str2,' ','split');
nums = cellfun(@(x) find(x == 'e'), words, 'UniformOutput', false);
[idx] = find(~cellfun(@isempty, nums));
wordList = words(idx)
wordList(wordList == 'e') = 'X'
```

Comment: Thank you, but I realised I was not specific enough.
I need to find X as you described, for example from
      str = 'I like carrots and pineapples and other fruit'
i need to obtain 'pineapples' and 'other', and then in these, I need to change 'e' for 'z', and return the changed words only, not the original statement.

Comment: @matlab-oh-no: See updated answer. It's a bit long, but again: I think it works =)

Comment: Hello, unfortunately, this code seems to write out all words which contain the letter 'e', regardless of whether or not they follow 'AND' (I made the whole text uppercase), with the list of words to choose from starting from the first words found after first 'AND' in the text. By what I undestrand, you meant 'str2' to contain only words after 'AND' already ?